# Casting to System Verilog struct and referencing member

Tags: system-verilog

I would like to cast a vector to a struct and extract a member in the same statement.   Is this possible?  Otherwise, I would have to assign to a temporary variable, which is ugly.

For example:

```
typedef struct packed { logic a; logic b; } struct_t;
struct_t my_struct;

logic [1:0] foo;
assign bar = struct_t'(foo).a;
```

^^^^^ This is apparently not allowed !   Why ?

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only person who finds this annoying! I asked almost exactly the same question on comp.lang.verilog (even using the word **ugly**!) - see [Accessing a structure member after a cast](http://www.edaboard.co.uk/accessing-a-structure-member-after-a-cast-t519016.html).

Comment: It appears that this kind of thing is still being discussed by the standards committee: http://www.eda.org/svdb/view.php?id=2735

Comment: FYI there's a syntax error in the original post. `{ logic a; logic b }` should be `{ logic a; logic b; }` (note the additional semicolon). I tried to edit the post but apparently edits need to be 6+ characters.

Answer (score 4):

I agree it would be nice to be able to do that, but it's not allowed in the language.  The SystemVerilog LRM (IEEE 1800-2009) explains this in Section 23.7.

> A hierarchical name and a member select into a structure, union, class or covergroup object share the same
>   syntactic form of a sequence of name components separated by periods. Such names are called dotted names
>   prior to the determination of whether the name is a hierarchical name or member select. The distinguishing
>   aspect of a hierarchical name is that the first component of the name must match a scope name while the first
>   name component of a member select must match a variable name. The general approach used is to attempt to
>   resolve the first name component immediately and to use the results of that resolution attempt to determine
>   how to treat the overall name.

Since you have `struct_t'(foo)` and not a variable name, it does not treat the `.a` as a member select.

Similarly, you CANNOT access a member of a class or structure that is returned from a function call like you could in C++.

```
function struct_t getStruct();
  // do something
endfunction

logic a;
a = getStruct().a;   // <= Not allowed
```

Comment: @dwinkle:  Yes, good answer.  Well, IMO they should definitely add that as an enhancement.  I was about to justify this by saying that my example is clearly well-defined from local context as just another way to say foo[1].
But this makes me realize that ".a is just another way to say [1] doesn't justify anything since  " (x+y)[1] " or even just " (foo)[1] " aren't allowed either.

Comment: @dwinkle: ....  I still claim that a typecast is different from an arbitrary expression.     But if I had may way, member access and part selection would be valid against arbitrary expressions too.   I might be wrong, but on first thought, this kind of thing is valid in C, C++, Python and Perl, etc.

Answer (score 2):

According to the spec, that doesn't look like valid syntax. I'm pretty sure member access is only allowed on identifiers, not any arbitrary expression.

Comment: Well, IMO this would be very useful.  For example, in the case I'm interested in, I'm defining a packed struct are a means of defining the fields of a value in a (software accessible) register.  So the registers themselves are just 64-bit vectors, but it is useful to cast back and forth between the vector and the struct definition for each register.   But this is not allowed!

Comment: So it is apparently an oversight.   @Adam12,  you say member access not allowed on arbitrary expressions.   Well, I claim this is not an arbitrary expression.  It is a typecast.